# Cannot vote on private chain. using dao tutorial

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, dao

I'm trying to do a little extra with the ethereum [dao tutorial](http://www.ethereum.org/dao) on a private chain with several nodes having different etherbases.

What I did is as follows,

- I created the contract, sent it some ether.
- Added some members (around 8). I can see the members and member count fine.
- I created a proposal.
- Finally selected the VoteOn method but get `Data cant be executed.` message.

There is a votes array in Proposal but something doesnt sit well with this line `p.votes[p.numberOfVotes]= Vote({inSupport: supportsProposal, voter: msg.sender, justification: justificationText});`

**EDIT**: My goal is to see the votes and justifications. Without the above line, all works well.

Here is a part of the contract

```
event Voted(uint proposalID, bool position, address voter, string justification);
...
struct Proposal {
    address recipient;
    uint amount;
    string description;
    uint votingDeadline;
    bool executed;
    bool proposalPassed;
    bool proposalCanRun;
    uint numberOfVotes;
    int remainingVotesToPass;
    int currentResult;
    bytes32 proposalHash;
    Vote[] votes;
    mapping (address => bool) voted;
}    

struct Vote {
    bool inSupport;
    address voter;
    string justification;
}
...
function voteOn(
    uint proposalNumber,
    bool supportsProposal,
    string justificationText
)
    onlyMembers
    returns (uint voteID)
{    

    Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];         // Get the proposal
    if (p.voted[msg.sender] == true) throw;         // If has already voted, cancel
    p.voted[msg.sender] = true;                     // Set this voter as having voted
    p.numberOfVotes++;                              // Increase the number of votes
    if (supportsProposal) {                         // If they support the proposal
        p.currentResult++;                          // Increase score
    } else {                                        // If they don't
        p.currentResult--;                          // Decrease the score
    }

    ...

    p.votes[p.numberOfVotes]= Vote({inSupport: supportsProposal, voter: msg.sender, justification: justificationText});   //form vote obj from given data and add vote to vote group 

    ...


    // Create a log of this event
    Voted(proposalNumber,  supportsProposal, msg.sender, justificationText);
}
...
```